# Local coordinates on Lorentzian manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, geodesic, semi-riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a globally hyperbolic spacetime, $S \subset M$ Cauchy hypersurface with unit normal vector field $n$, $\Sigma \subset S$ compact 2-dim. submanifold with unit normal vector field $\nu$.

I have a defined function $\exp: (- \epsilon, \epsilon) \times \sigma \rightarrow M$ defined via $\exp(r,p)=c_p(r)$ where $c_p$ is the null geodesic with $c^{'}_p(0)=n_p+\nu_p$. 
Let $q=\exp(r_0,p)$ where $q$ is not a critical value for $\exp$.
One can define local coordinates $(t,u,x^2,x^3)$ on some neighborhood $V$ of $q$ with $\varphi$ a local parametrization around $p$ and using the map

$(u,r,x^2,x^3) \mapsto \exp(r, \psi_u(\varphi(x^2,x^3)))$

with $\psi_u$ as the flow along the timelike geodesics orthogonal to $S$. 
Now we have $g(\partial_r,\partial_r)=0$ and we can compute using properties of the Levi-Civita connection, that

$\dfrac{\partial g(\partial_r, \partial_{\mu})}{\partial r}=0$
for $\mu=0,1,2,3$. Now my book says "Since $g_{ru}=-1$ and $g_{r2}=g_{r3}=0$ on $\psi_u(\Sigma)$ we get $g_{ru}=-1$ and $g_{r2}=g_{r3}=0$ on $V$" but I just can't see where this comes from.. why is $g_{ru}=-1$ on $\psi_u(\Sigma)$??

Comment: I'm pretty sure the metric has been defined somewhere in the book you're reading (by the way, which book is it?).

Comment: It's the book from Leonor Godinho José Natário: An Introduction to Riemannian Geometry, I can't find a definition, I think that we assume $(M,g)$ to be a Lorentzian manifold, but that's it I think

Comment: I'm thinking of the matrix generating Lorentzian transformations of a Minkowski space (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space#Lorentz_transformations_and_symmetry)), which bears a resemblance with the $g_{ru}$ and the other values you mention.

Comment: Hm, I'm not quite sure if I understand this, if I have some metric on $g$ then its representation matrix is the same foll all coordinates right? It does not change through a transformation, does it..?

Comment: Not right. The representation matrix does change depending on our coordinates. However, the metric doesn't actually change. There are some properties (called invariants, you'll come to them later on) that are what actually characterise the metric. These things don't change when we change our coordinates.

Comment: Does the determinant of the representation matrix change?

Comment: No. Think that the rep. matrix in the new coordinates is the conjugate of the old one by the change of coordinates matrix. Conjugation by elements of the general linear group (this is where matrices of change of coordinates lie) does not alter the determinant.